# Spring OneToMany - how to limit list of objects to list of one field from that object

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I wonder if it's possible to fetch List of some specific field of objects instead of list of whole objects from relation `@OneToMany`:

```
@Entity
public class Template
...
private Driver driver;
prvate boolean isIpen;

@OneToMany(

            mappedBy = "template"
    )
    private List<Warehouse> warehouses = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to fetch list of Template objects with list of `Warehouse.name` (`List<String>`) instead of `List<Warehouse>`. Is it possible?

My repository:

```
@QueryHints(value = {
            @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false")
    })
    @Query("SELECT at FROM Template at " +
            "WHERE at.driver.id = :companyId " +
            "AND at.isOpen = true")
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"warehouses"})
    List<Template> findAllOpenByCompanyId(Long companyId, Pageable pageable);
```

I wanto to reduce the number of queries to database

Answer (score 1):

I would try using an `@ElementCollection` with `@CollectionTable` instead of the `@OneToMany`.

So it would turn like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Template
...
private Driver driver;
prvate boolean isIpen;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
    name="the name of the warehouse table",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="warehouse id column")
)
@Column(name="warehouse name column in warehouse table")
private List<String> warehouseNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

I'm unable to test this at the moment, but hopefully it helps.